# dd command file_operations involved?

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, storage, dd

When we are executing dd command, which write function gets called. 
As per my understanding, dd command is not filesystem specific, so no file system's file_operations is involved. Please correct If I am wrong here.

I would like to know which file_operations is involved in carrying out dd operation?

Comment: You can look at the source (GNU coreutils), or use `strace`.

Comment: Thanks Diego. dd uses write system call. But, I am looking for what's happening inside kernel. Which specific file_operations inside kernel is getting calling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you write to.

Either it is a regular file and file system specific calls are used or it is a device and you eventually use to the target disk (or whatever) underlying driver.

http://www.makelinux.net/books/ulk3/understandlk-CHP-14-SECT-5#understandlk-CHP-14-SECT-5

Answer (score 0):

The write system call does indeed end up invoking the file system specific write via the VFS layer. See the [vfs_write](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.7.1/fs/read_write.c#L427) function.